# accessing netCDF data when start variables are stored as matrices and not vectors

Tags: r, netcdf

I am working with the North American Regional Reanalysis (NARR data set) which is stored as a netCDF file. I have some familiarity with netCDF format however, I am currently stumped. 
I am trying to access Uwind speed using the uwnd.10m.mon.mean.nc file.

Generally when accessing variables I have used the standard code:

```
var <- get.var.ncdf(nc, varid=NA, start=NA, count=NA, verbose=FALSE,signedbyte=TRUE,         forcevarid=NA)
```

where the start variable is in the format of x-y-z-t. In previous experiences I have put a latitude starting code, longitude starting code and time where the lat, long and time where each stored as one vector.

However, my problem now is that the longitude is stored in the aforementioned data set as a matrix of (x,y) as well as latitude (x,y). So, I have a specific longitude that I want to chose which is in the format of long[271,1] and a specific latitude lat[1,137]. When I put this into the start=NA section it doesn't like it and I get an error.

How do I enter the lats and longs starting values in the form of x-y-z-t if each lat and long has their own specific x,y values? The code below gives me an error because it obviously does not like the start=NA format.

```
UwndJu2006_A= get.var.ncdf(Uwnd, "uwnd", start=c([271,1], [1,137] ,330), count=c(1,1,1))
```

This might be a simple question but I am at a loss. 
All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

So you want to extract the measurements for all the times specifically at long 271, lat 137? It looks like the `uwnd` varaible is just indexed by `[x,y,time]` so

```
library(ncdf)
nc <- open.ncdf("uwnd.10m.mon.mean.nc")
uwnd <- get.var.ncdf(nc, "uwnd", start=c(271,137,1), count=c(1,1,-1))
```

would seem to open that part. Here I used count to only use those long/lat values while getting all the time values. You can verify the lat/long coordinates for those indexes with

```
get.var.ncdf(nc, "lat", start=c(271,137), count=c(1,1))
get.var.ncdf(nc, "lon", start=c(271,137), count=c(1,1))
```